# jQuery "return { foo: bar, foo2: bar2 }" - What is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to teach myself jQuery/Javascript and I am going through the [Avgrund source](https://github.com/hakimel/avgrund), I am unsure as to the **exact** purpose of the return statement in `avgrund.js`.

Is it functioning like some kind of pseudo-class? In Avgrund's `index.html` the function, as defined here: `var Avgrund = (function(){ ...` seems to be being called my members of the return statement/function or whatever technical name that has.

This:

```
return {
    activate: activate,
    deactivate: deactivate,
    disableBlur: disableBlur,
    show: show,
    hide: hide
}
```

Is this just a way of restricting how `function_name` can be called? So, I can only call `function_name. [ activate / deactivate / disableBlur / show / hide ]`.

And, after the colon are those the function names to be invoked? For instance,

`method: lemon`. If I called `Avgrund.method()` it would invoke the function `lemon`.

Overall I am looking for an explanation of this return syntax, am I on the right path here?

And what is this type of structure called so I can replicate it in Coffeescript?

Comment: value represented in `object`

Comment: [*MDN:* Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

Comment: [Revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Answer (score 2):

This is basically shorthand to creating an object in JS. This:

```
return {
    activate: activate,
    deactivate: deactivate,
    disableBlur: disableBlur,
    show: show,
    hide: hide
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var x = new Object();
x.activate = activate;
x.deactivate = deactivate;
x.disableBlur = disableBlur;
x.show = show;
x.hide = hide;

return x;
```

This call: `var x = {}` is the same as `var x = new Object()`

Answer (score 1):

The return value is an **object**

```
function fun() {
   return {
     activate: activate,
     deactivate: deactivate,
     disableBlur: disableBlur,
     show: show,
     hide: hide
  }
}

var obj = fun();
console.log(obj['deactivate']); //obj.deactivate
```

Comment: `obj[deactivate]` would cause an reference error if there is no `deactivate` variable in the current scope. Probably what you want is `obj['deactivate']`

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path; it's called the Revealing Module Pattern.

[Read about module patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) and the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) in Addy Osmani's book on design patterns. It's a great resource.

Comment: +1 for the link to the JS design patterns book! Had no idea it's available for free

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, it returns an object.

In this example, you can encapsulate functions and variables within `Test`. By returning an object literal, you can essentially control what the end user is allowed to call.

```
var Test = (function() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hello thar.");
  };
  var test2 = function() {
    console.log("nope");
  };
  return {
    test: test
  };
})();
Test.test();
Test.test2(); // syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on JavaScript Patterns - http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/

It seems that what you are referring to is the Revealing Module Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can create anonymous objects. In javascript objects are actually associative arrays.

So basically if you want to create an object in JavaScript one of the many ways is:

```
var obj = {};
```

**So the code you provided means that you are trying to return an object and "activate", "deactivate" .. are the properties of this object.**

Kindly read this post you will get a better idea.

http://3dmdesign.com/development/javascript-variables-and-anonymous-objects

Comment: [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are not associative arrays. You're thinking about hash-maps, which are data structures that use hashing.

Comment: I was just referring to key and value. Just to make sure that a person understands properly.

Comment: I don't see how a person can understand properly if you are giving misleading information. A hash is the result of a hashing function applied to something. A JS object is not the result of a hash function. A JS object is a map (=collection of key-value pairs=associative array) which incidentally uses hashing (hash-table) to improve efficiency.

Comment: I have done research and can't see that you are wrong. Let me edit my answer and +1 for your correction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first part is a variable declaration `var Avgrund` that is set to what is called an "IIFE" Immediately Invoked Function, you might hear it called a "Self Invoked Function as well, it is different phrases for the same thing. Here is the syntax for an "IIFE" `(function() {...} )();` in the function that you shown it returns and object  `{ }` more on that object later.

The sign for an Immediately Invoked function in Javascript is that opening parentheses `(` before the keyword function. At the end of that function you will notice a pair of parentheses '()' that is telling javascript to run invoked this function right away.

That "IIFE" is returning an object. In javascript objects are represented by sets of `key:value` pairs separated  by a comma `,` enclosed in curly braces `{ }`. So `var emptyObject = {}` is an empty object.

In other languagues they call this a hash, map, associative array and dictionary but all essentially are a collections of `key:value` pairs.

```
 return {
   activate: activate,
   deactivate: deactivate,
   disableBlur: disableBlur,
   show: show,
   hide: hide
 }
```

In the source code you have functions for example activate that are enclosed within that functional scope of the "IIFE" so what that returned object is doing is exposing those functions for you to use. So `show: show` for example is not invoking the function at that time, the sign of that is no `()` after the function name, it is only saying hey the show value here remember `key:value` is a function. So else where in your code you will call it and invoke it `Avgrund.show(...)` like that did in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JavaScript have scoped visibility. That means that an inner function is only visible within an outer function. E.g.:

```
function outer() {
    function inner() {
    }
    function callInner() {
        inner(); // OK
    }
}
inner(); // ReferenceError: inner() not defined
```

In case of Avgrund:

```
function Avgrund () {
    function disableBlur() {
        console.log('disableBlur called');
    }

    function print() {
        // I can see other functions inside Avgrund
        disableBlur();
    }
}
```

Since in our example Avgrund is defined as a named function, it will be visible in the global object (`window` object in browsers). Named functions inside of Avgrund however, are not visible outside of the Avgrud object itself. In order to get access to these functions we can return them:

```
function Avgrund () {
    function disableBlur() {
        console.log('disableBlur called');
    }

    function print() {
        // I can see other functions inside Avgrund
        disableBlur();
    }

    return {
        print: printShow
    }
}
```

Avgrund is defined as a constructor function (that is a function used to create new objects). So Avgrund is defined but never executed. Lets run this function and see what happens:

```
var avg = (function Avgrund () {
    function disableBlur() {
        console.log('disableBlur called');
    }

    function print() {
        // I can see other functions inside Avgrund
        disableBlur();
    }

    return {
        print: print
    }
})();
```

Now our new instance of Avgrund returned an object, containing a reference to a function `print()` inside of Avgrund itself. We can access it now from outside of Avgrund:

```
avg.print() // disableBlur called
```

And now to answer your question. As you have already correctly guessed, this construct (returning an object of references to inner functions) is used to restrict access to methods within Avgrund. Essentially defining public API functions of Avgrund and separating them from functions intended to be used as private ones.

This pattern is called `Revealing Module Pattern`, as mentioned by misterkeg and DotNetHaggis.

As others have already stated, the returned type is a simple object.